# How can I hide a <p> without ID, inside a div with ID and Class, in css?

Tags: html, css

This is so frustrating, I'm trying to hide an specific paragraph, but it doesn't have an ID:

```
<div id="form-2" class="widget widget-box w-widget">
<p style>Some text 1</p>
<p style>Some text 2</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is no ID for P.
I already tried like this:

```
#form-2 p {
display: none;
}
```

But it is hiding all the paragraphs. Also tried using the class, same result.

PS: Need to hide  Some text 1

and leave  Some text 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector (or just [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) / [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selector) you can use as well the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector (or just the [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) / [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) selector)

here is a few snippets based on yours

#### first-child

```css
#form-2 p:first-child {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="form-2" class="widget widget-box w-widget">
  <p>Some text 1</p>
  <p>Some text 2</p>
</div>
```

#### last-child

```css
#form-2 p:last-child {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="form-2" class="widget widget-box w-widget">
  <p>Some text 1</p>
  <p>Some text 2</p>
</div>
```

#### nth-child

```css
#form-2 p:nth-child(3) {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="form-2" class="widget widget-box w-widget">
  <p>Some text 1</p>
  <p>Some text 2</p>
  <p>Some text 3</p>
  <p>Some text 4</p>
  <p>Some text 5</p>
</div>
```

#### nth-of-type

```css
#form-2 p:nth-of-type(4) {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="form-2" class="widget widget-box w-widget">
  <p>Some text 1</p>
  <p>Some text 2</p>
  <p>Some text 3</p>
  <p>Some text 4</p>
  <p>Some text 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `first-child`.

```
#form-2 p:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr54f2bn/)

Answer (score 3):

```
#form-2 > p:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What does "first-of-type" mean?

Comment: The first element that matches the type `<p>`. This approach hides the first paragraph, regardless of any other elements within the div

Comment: Also, the `>` means that it only affects paragraphs that are immediate children of the div, not just any paragraphs within the div

Answer (score 2):

Try this `#form-2 p:first-child`

Answer (score 2):

You can do `nth-child(1)`, `nth-child` is used for an arbitrary child. If you happen to just want to hide the first `<p>` then you can use `:first-child`.

```
#form-2 p:nth-child(1) {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a fiddle. Your was the most appropriated. Thx for everyone that answered

Answer (score 1):

You need to select first `p` tag using `:first-child`

```
#form-2 p:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```